# Matlab value class - anyway to change attribute of property from constructor?

Tags: matlab

I want to create a class in Matlab which represents a graph. The class in default has 2 properties: a normal property `E` which means `adjacency matrix`, and a dependent property `adjL` which means `adjacency list`. The default constructor will be something like `g = graph(E)`, and `g.adjL` is calculated based on `g.E`.

I want to ask if there is anyway so when i have another parameter i.e `g = graph(A, 'adjlist')`, an object will be created with property `adjL` now becomes normal property `g.adjL= A` and property `E` now becomes dependent (calculated based on `g.adjL`)?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. The `dependent` nature of a property is static, and defined by the attributes you give it when you define the class. It can't be changed on a per-instance basis.

But you can still get the behavior that you want. What you could do is make both `E` and `adjL` dependent, and have two other properties `realE` and `realAdjL` that hold actual data. Have the getters for `E` and `adjL` look at both those fields, and derive their values from whichever one is present.

You don't even necessarily need to make `E` and `adjL` dependent to have this work. You could just define getters and setters for `E` and `adjL` (like `get.E` and `set.E`) that examine both of their underlying fields and reconstruct the observable values for those properties from whichever field is populated.

Comment: sorry for late response. For making both `E` and `adjL` dependent, pls see my comment in Mohsen's answer. I also thought about writing getters and setters, it seems the only way to keep the `up-to-date` property although both now are stored in object. But this leads me to another question: in case `E` is normal property, should i use dependent property `adjL`, or should i write a method `obj.adjL`? You have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can have both `E` and `adjL` defined as dependent and have a source property that contains the actual value together with a flag that describes its source and then define the getter methods to decide if the actual source should be returned or a conversion is needed:

```matlab
classdef graph
    properties (Access=private)
        sourcetype
        source
    end

    properties (Dependent)
        E
        adjL
    end

    methods
        function obj = graph(varargin)
            if nargin==1,
                obj.sourcetype = 'edge';
                obj.source = varargin{1};
            elseif nargin==2 && strcmp(varargin{2}, 'adjL')
                obj.sourcetype = 'adjL';
                obj.source = varargin{1};
            else
                error('Invalid input arguments');
            end
        end

        function ret = get.E(obj)
            if strcmp(obj.sourcetype, 'edge')
                ret = obj.source;
            else
                % convert source from adjL to E
            end
        end

        function ret = get.adjL(obj)
            if strcmp(obj.sourcetype, 'adjL')
                ret = obj.source;
            else
                % convert source from E to adjL
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: this is the proper answer, im deleting mine.

Comment: sorry for late response. This way works only when you never change value of `E` and `adjL` after constructor. And consequently, the property of `dependent relationship` becomes useless ...

Comment: You just need to add `set.E` and `set.adjL` setter methods as well. E.g. `function obj = set.E(obj, newE); obj.sourcetype = 'edge'; obj.source = newE; end`.